# Render different in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've just finish a navbar but strangely and I don't get why, it is not rendering the same on firefox and chrome.

I'll show you the difference, do you have an idea where this can come from ?

Chrome (normale) :
[image: Chrome]

Firefox and IE: 
[image: Firefox]

As an hint (possibly), I use the propriety `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` but if I play with it I dont see any changement relevant.

Here is link to the website if you want to do yourself an idea : [origin](http://www.agencedevoyage.com/)
And here is a link to a fiddle just with the navigator : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/xcrg9tqL/)

I'm still new to cross browser development so if someone has an hint for me.. ?

Comment: You can remove all those vendor prefixes except for the ms- ones since they've worked in modern browsers for quite some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like a float isn't clearing properly in certain browsers due to slight pixel differences in font rendering.

Try adding `clear:both` to your navigation bar. This should force it to clear all floats.

Answer (score -1):

You can chose one of these options to solve your problem.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `#header`.

Add `float:left;` to the `#main-menu`

Add `clear:both` to the `#main-menu`